# C++ Errors (but why ?)

Tags: c++

I am teaching myself C++ and have been struggling with this rudimentary piece of code, that I can't seem to finesse or figure out what exactly is my error. I'm seeking to create a logic-based word game and it's not executing and/or freeing itself of compiling errors.

Any tips ?

Thanks !

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int y = 1;
    int n = 2;
    int i;
    int choice;
    int choose() {
    if (1)
        std::cout << "Is 1 greater than 2 ? Please enter '1' for Yes or '2' for No.\n";
    else(2);
    std::cout << "That's not right man. Ugh... Would you like to try again ?\n";

    std::cout << "Choice: ";
    std::cin >> choice;

    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            std::cout << "Okay, you're getting better (and smarter too).\n";
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "Whatever man ! it's all just a big ol' mind trick anyway, right ? ;-)\n";
    }
    system("pause");
    return choice;
    switch (choice) {
        case 3:
            std::cout << "Would you like to try again ?" << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            std::cout << "Okey Dokey, well... bye-bye now !" << endl;
    }
}
}


 return 0;
```

---

Here are the compiling errors:

---

```
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\fpina\ClionProjects\FrederickPina\cmake-build-debug --target FrederickPina -- -j 2
Scanning dependencies of target FrederickPina
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/FrederickPina.dir/main.cpp.obj
C:\Users\fpina\ClionProjects\FrederickPina\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\fpina\ClionProjects\FrederickPina\main.cpp:10:18: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
     int choose() {
                  ^
C:\Users\fpina\ClionProjects\FrederickPina\main.cpp: At global scope:
C:\Users\fpina\ClionProjects\FrederickPina\main.cpp:37:9: error: expected unqualified-id before 'return'
         return 0;
         ^~~~~~
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\FrederickPina.dir\build.make:62: CMakeFiles/FrederickPina.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:72: CMakeFiles/FrederickPina.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:84: CMakeFiles/FrederickPina.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: FrederickPina] Error 2
```

Comment: Exactly which error have you encountered?

Comment: It would be very useful if you provided said compiling errors.

Comment: What errors? Where?

Comment: You are declaring nested function    `int choose()` inside `main()`
.

Comment: `int choose()` is a function definition declared inside `main`.  Nested function definitions are not allowed in C++.

Comment: To help interpret errors: `main.cpp:10` means line 10 of file main.cpp.  That tells you exactly where the compiler got to when it found something wrong.  It then prints `error: a function-definition is not allowed here` which tells you pretty specifically what the problem is.

Comment: Be careful of your semicolon placement. Your formatter not indenting line 14 is telling you it wouldn't get executed as part of the `else` on line 13. Also, you may want to review your if/else logic--the `else` is a syntax error and your `if` always executes.

Comment: If you haven't set high warning levels, you may want to do so: the compiler will give you a lot of scary warning messages, but most of them will be pointing out parts of your code that behave non-intuitively, are difficult to reason about, or are common mistakes.

If a warning message confuses you, you can usually google the warning codes for compilers to get more in-depth information about why they're appearing, though you may have to sift through documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You are already inside a function here, and you can't define a function inside of another one in c++, so this is invalid:

```
int choose() {
```

Even if `choose` was defined outside of `main`, the `choice` variable doesn't exist in the scope of `choose` function, so these lines are invalid for that reason:

```
std::cin >> choice;

switch (choice) {
    ...
return choice;
```

`1` always resolves to true, so this always happens, which is not your intent:

```
if (1)
    std::cout << "Is 1 greater than 2 ? Please enter '1' for Yes or '2' for No.\n";
```

`else`doesn't take any parameters. If you changed your code so that the above `if` statement was sometimes false, this part would evaluate `(2);` as a statement, which does nothing, which is not your intent:

```
else(2);
```

This line is meant to come after the else, but it is not in any block that comes immediately after a conditional statement, so it always happens, which is not your intent:

```
std::cout << "That's not right man. Ugh... Would you like to try again ?\n";
```

This code immediately follows a return statement in the same function, so will never evaluate:

```
switch (choice) {
    case 3:
        std::cout << "Would you like to try again ?" << endl;
        break;
    case 4:
        std::cout << "Okey Dokey, well... bye-bye now !" << endl;
}
```

You don't have a `return` statement in your main function, which is invalid because it must return an `int`. Instead you have this `return` statement outside of any function altogether, which is also invalid.

```
return 0;
```